# Applying same styles to parent and nested children

Tags: sass

I have following css rule

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

I also want to apply same style rules to `*::after` and `*::before`, and I can do so via `*, *::after, *::before {}`. However I want to keep it consistent with other scss I have that is nested, hence I'm trying to figure out how to nest these pseudo elements, yet apply same style to all 3 of these selectors.

Comment: Could you explain a bit the last part? What are you trying to avoid exactly by using `, *::after, *::before {}`? Could you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) this way:

```
* {
  &, &::after, &::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  }
}
```

It will compile as:

```
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```